# What are the most common shortcuts you use?

Tags: shortcut-keys, productivity

I'm a windows guy and I'm really trying to get into using linux. I've just installed ubuntu and am missing all of my windows shortcuts like:

- `Win+E` open file browser
- `Win+R cmd` open the command prompt

There are a lot more but these two I use constantly. I'm looking for things that are going to make me a lot more productive a lot quicker.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to **System -> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts**.   You'll see a list of the default configured and configurable shortcuts, including the ones for launching a web browser or terminal.
You'll be able to set these (within some limits) as you like.

Setting a file browser to launch appears to be a bit trickier.   [GeekGumbo](http://www.geekgumbo.com/) has a terrific blog entry on setting up Windows-like shortcuts, which is probably worth checking out :  [Keyboard shortcut to File Manager in Ubuntu (Windows + E for Nautilus)](http://www.geekgumbo.com/2010/10/14/keyboard-shortcut-to-file-manager-in-ubuntu-windows-e-for-nautilus/)

Comment: I've mapped *Super* ("win") + *C* for opening a terminal, which I'm frequently using.

Comment: I don't think it is better to make your own shortcuts instead of learning the defaults. If I make my own shortcuts they won't work with another installation.

Answer (score 3):

I use xbindkeys, which lets you associate keyboard shortcuts to any possible command - you can get some really complicated things through that. I mostly just use it to control my music player, but you can do pretty much anything with it.

You can install and run it like so:

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xbindkeys-config
xbindkeys-config
```

Instructions here: http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html